# D3.js Stacked Bar Chart adding percentage label on each bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to learn how to use D3.js and I am using this stacked bar code as a example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768. I wanted to add a label on top of each bar that shows the percentage of wounds, other or disease. What code should I add to the original code from the example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add label on the top of bar. You will need to append text element to each bar. Because this is a stacked bar chart it will make sense to add the notation on top of each colored bar. You can take example of how a rectangle is appended same way you can append text. Here is working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/i7dTZMVAQUdSyawz3SVR?p=preview) link .

```
var labels_new = cause.selectAll("text")
    .data(Object)
    .enter().append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "stackbartext")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y) + 20;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      if (d.y0 === 0 && d.y === 0)
        return "";
      else {
        return ("" + d.y0 + "," + d.y);
      }
    })
    .style("font", "10px")
    .attr("transform", "translate(5,-10)");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what data does ".data(Object)" refer to in this case. Also, can we do some calculation for the data in this case? For example, calculating the percentage of each color in the stacked bar.

Comment: The object has your csv data context. d.x refers to x axes and d.y and d.y0 has wounds and others (look at the console.log statements). I added a percentage calculation to give you example. You can change the calculation to be what you like. See this updated [link] (http://plnkr.co/edit/i7dTZMVAQUdSyawz3SVR?p=preview)

Comment: To learn about how d3 parses data check out this link http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1525346 example or http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 these examples doesn't have any javascript to parse the csv (i.e d3.csv) already.